# Convert dataset of points with each x and y separate to list of points

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
     x0  y0  x1  y1  x2  y2
0     0   5   1   5   1   4
1     1   5   1   4   2   4
2     1   4   2   4   2   3
3     2   4   2   3   3   3
4     2   3   3   3   3   2
```

This I gathered reading a csv that looks like this:

```
    x0  y0  x1  y1  x2  y2  x5  y5
0   0   5   1   5   1   4   3   3
1   1   5   1   4   2   4   3   2
2   1   4   2   4   2   3   4   2
3   2   4   2   3   3   3   4   1
4   2   3   3   3   3   2   5   1
```

And I need a list that combines each row into a separate sub-list, so like this:

```
list = [[[0, 5], [1, 5], [1, 4]], 
        [[1, 5], [1, 4], [2, 4]], ...]
```

I can't really find an easy way for this on the rest of StackOverflow and am wondering if there even is an easy way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

What I have tried thus far is simply converting it to a list and then looping through it and appending each two items to a new list, like this:

```
path_df = pd.read_csv("data/preprocessed_data.csv", sep="\t", index_col=0)

X_points = path_df[["x0", "y0", "x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"]].values.tolist()

X = []

for x in X_points:
    p1 = [x[0], x[1]]
    p2 = [x[2], x[3]]
    p3 = [x[4], x[5]]
    row = [p1, p2, p3]
    X.append(row)

print(X[:10])
```

This does give me the desired output but does not feel very *pythonic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,3,2).tolist()
```

Result:

```
[[[0, 5], [1, 5], [1, 4]], [[1, 5], [1, 4], [2, 4]], [[1, 4], [2, 4], [2, 3]], [[2, 4], [2, 3], [3, 3]], [[2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 2]]]
```

Comment: This is a lot cleaner and pythonic I think, thank you!